# Google Login not working on Firebase App Distribution builds

Tags: android, google-signin, firebase-app-distribution

We have google login (that requires server side communication) setup on our Android application which we are distributing using Firebase App Distribution.
We are having an issue with google login not working on the firebase distributed builds. `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: Account authorization fail`

I have tried solving this issue by adding SHA 1 from our CI machine to the firebase project and updating the `google-services.json` file. This did not work, same error message.

I read that Firebase App Distribution generates new test certificates for AABs. Is this also true for APKs?
While there were hints on how to find test certificates for distributed AABs and fix the issue with social logins, I could not find anything for APKs.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Upload your manifest file.

Comment: @UnwantedCoder Hi there. I cant see how `AndroidManifest.xml` would be necessary, considering there is nothing related to google login or app distribution there. I have included the `google_play_services_version` in the meta data if that's your concern.

Comment: Please check you have both meta-data: <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /><meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="PASTE_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" />

Comment: @UnwantedCoder I do not have the `geo.API_KEY`